# How to initiate "USER_PASSWORD" sign in flow in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

We are trying to migrate the Cognito user pool in our system.
To do this, we do need to use "USER_PASSWORD" AuthenticationType, as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-dg.pdf):

```
Your app sends the username and password to Amazon Cognito. If your app has a native sign-in
UI and uses the Cognito Identity Provider SDK, your app must use the USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
flow, in which the SDK sends the password to the server (your app must not use the
default USER_SRP_AUTH flow since the SDK does not send the password to the server
in the SRP authentication flow). The USER_PASSWORD_AUTH flow is enabled by setting
AuthenticationDetails.authenticationType to "USER_PASSWORD".
```

The [Cognito documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/index.html) does not explain how to do this.

[This thread](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/1051) states we need to use
android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider SDK in order to specify the AuthenticationType.

Could you please refer me to one example or code snipped on how to implement this use case using the aforementioned SDK? I can't understand how to do this with the javadoc documentation referred - The javadocs explain how to build one AuthenticationDetails object with the desired authentication type, but I don't know what to do with it.
How could I effectively start the authentication flow with the manually constructed AuthenticationDetails?
Our app is currently using the Amplitude SDK extensively for sign-in and authentication features.
If we use `android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider` to sign in with "USER_PASSWORD", will the existing code be compatible with it?
For example, will the app be able to get the id tokens using `AwsMobileClient.getTokens()`, will the automatic refreshment of expired tokens work, and will the "reset forgotten password" use case work?

I'm using:

```
com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.16.10
com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.16.10
com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoauth:2.16.10
```